# Triple booting, what do I do now?

Tags: release-freya, system-installation

What do I do now? Windows 7 and 10 are installed and I can't install on the free space shown as unusable below.

[image: Here is a picture of how the installation process looks like]

Comment: If possible can you add output of `sudo fdisk -l`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From screenshot it is clear you have **four primary partitions**.

Refer [Disk partitioning](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Disk_partitioning):

> The total data storage space of a PC HDD can contain **at most four primary partitions**, or alternatively **three primary partitions and an extended partition**.

To rectify this, you would need to remove a partition, replace it with an Extended Partition, then use logical partitions within that Extended Partition to get more than 4 partitions onto the drive.

Comment: Please let me know if you solved and you can accept the answer by clicking tick at left of this answer @MichaelWong